# Unable to access element created by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After the creation of a new element in my list, I want to insert content into it. I know I could do this while creating, but the problem is that I cannot interact with the element after creation.

```js
var buttoncounter = 5;
for (i = 0; i <= (newtrack_information.length - 1); i++) {
  $("#tracklist").append("<li class=\"ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle\"><span><a id=" + buttoncounter + "\" href=\"#\"></a></span></li>");
  $("#" + buttoncounter).html(newtrack_information[i].trackname + " - " + newtrack_information[i].artist);
  buttoncounter++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="tracklist">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span><a id="0" href="#"></a></span>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span><a id="1" href="#"></a></span>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span><a id="2" href="#"></a></span>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span><a id="3" href="#"></a></span>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span><a id="4" href="#"></a></span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

If I try to find the respective element with

```
console.log($(document.body).find("#" + buttoncounter));
```

I get this:

```
[prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: body, selector: "#tracklist #5"]
```

**EDIT:**
Also, if I try to change the selector to "#tracklist #5" - it doesn't work either.

Comment: You're creating elements with the same `id` (`buttoncounter`)

Comment: sorry - forgot to add a line of the code

Comment: When you call your `console.log` after the loop then `buttoncounter` is always `+ 1` to the last element added, because of the `buttoncounter++` at the end of your loop.

Comment: Css and jQuery provide index functionality, you should not set numeric id for each of li, you can simply select it using indexes https://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've missed a `"` in your code. Use `...id=\"" +` instead of `...id=" +`. To avoid that, I recommend to use both single quotations `'` and double quotations `"` in the code like:

```
  $('#tracklist').append('<li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle"><span><a id="' + buttoncounter + '" href="#"></a></span></li>');
```

After altering that, you can add items from `newtrack_information` to your list.

```js
var buttoncounter = 5;

var newtrack_information = [
  {trackname: 1, artist: 'bob' },
  {trackname: 2, artist: 'jason' },
]

for (i = 0; i <= (newtrack_information.length - 1); i++) {
  $("#tracklist").append("<li class=\"ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle\"><span><a id=\"" + buttoncounter + "\" href=\"#\"></a></span></li>");
  $("#" + buttoncounter).html(newtrack_information[i].trackname + " - " + newtrack_information[i].artist);
  buttoncounter++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="tracklist">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span><a id="0" href="#"></a></span>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span><a id="1" href="#"></a></span>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span><a id="2" href="#"></a></span>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span><a id="3" href="#"></a></span>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span><a id="4" href="#"></a></span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: What's the down vote for? Please leave the comment to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the value of buttoncounter. It will always insert your values into the same id.

```
var buttoncounter = 5;
for (i = 0; i <= (newtrack_information.length - 1); i++) {
  $("#tracklist").append("<li class=\"ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle\"><span><a id=" + buttoncounter + "\" href=\"#\"></a></span></li>");
  $("#" + buttoncounter).html(newtrack_information[i].trackname + " - " + newtrack_information[i].artist);
  buttoncounter = buttoncounter - 1;
}
```

Try the below one see if it is solving your problem..

Comment: As mentioned in the comments of my question, in the first run I forgot to add that line of code here in the question.